# How to search in the array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have code:

```
$acceptFormat = array(
  'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
  'jpg' => 'image/jpg',
  'png' => 'image/png'
);

if ($ext != "jpg" && $ext != "jpeg" && $ext != "png") {
  throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
}

$mime = mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]);
if ($mime != "image/jpeg" && $mime != "image/jpg" && $mime != "image/png") {
   throw new RuntimeException('Invalid mime format.');
}
```

I have an `$acceptFormat` array with allowed file formats and two ify:

1. `if ($ mime! = "Image / jpeg" && $ mime! = "Image / jpg" && $ mime! = "Image / png")`
2. `if ($ ext! = "Jpg" && $ ext! = "Jpeg" && $ ext! = "Png")`

Is it possible to somehow modify this if to check extensions and mime type based on acceptFormat array?

Comment: try with `in_array()`

Comment: `if ( ! isset($acceptFormat[$ext]))`, `if ( ! in_array($mime, $acceptFormat, true))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `in_array()` , `array_keys()` for file **extension** and `array_values()` for **mime** value. Let's see,

```
<?php

$acceptFormat = array(
  'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
  'jpg' => 'image/jpg',
  'png' => 'image/png'
);

$ext ='jpg'; // demo value

if (!in_array($ext,array_keys($acceptFormat))) {
  throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
}

$mime = 'video/mkv'; // demo value

if (!in_array($mime,array_values($acceptFormat))) {
   throw new RuntimeException('Invalid mime format.');
}
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/aNdMM

Comment: What if the file extension is `.jpg` but the mimetype is `image/png` ?

Comment: @nikksan then just need to use `foreach()` on **$acceptFormat**  to validate extension and mime both with some validation flag :) simple

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = "path.ext";

$acceptFormat = array(
  'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
  'jpg' => 'image/jpg',
  'png' => 'image/png'
);

$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if(! array_key_exists($ext, $acceptFormat)) throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');

$mime = mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]);
if(! in_array($mime, $acceptFormat)) throw new RuntimeException('Invalid mime format.');
```

You need [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) for searching through the keys. And of course, you need [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to grab the extension.

Next, you need [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to search through the values for mime type.

Comment: in_array — Checks if a **value** exists in an array, so with this line `if(! in_array($mime)) throw new RuntimeException('Invalid mime format.');` you missed the `$acceptFormat ` variable

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
 $acceptFormat = array(
    'jpeg'  => 'image/jpeg',
    'jpg'   => 'image/jpg',
    'png'   => 'image/png'
);

$isValid = false;

foreach ($acceptFormat as $extension => $mimeType) {
    if ($ext === $extension && $mime === $mimeType) {
        $isValid = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!$isValid) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Invalid extension/mime type.');
}

// All is good..
```